# Re-consume message from kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, producer-consumer, consumer

I have an application that listens to a Kafka topic and reads 1 message from it in 1 thread. After reading a message, there is a certain logic, during which there are two options - everything is successful and a commit occurs call method ...acknowledge() to offset the offset and move on to the next message, or everything is unsuccessful and this message must be read again and the offset is not committed (...acknowledge() is not called)

If I do not call Acknowledge (), then shouldn't the consumer go on all reports in the topic and then go to the second circle, re-read the messages on which Acknowledge () was not called? Or how can I configure it?

I'm using spring-kafka and the following settings are specified:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=1
```

And I programmatically set the settings:

```
...setGroupId("test");
...setSyncCommits(true);
...setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
...setConcurrency(1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; Kafka maintains two pointers, the last committed offset and the current position. They are completely unrelated, except the current position is set to the last committed offset when a consumer first starts.

Not acknowledging (committing the offset) of a record does not change the current position.

You cannot continue processing other records after the failure because their offsets will override the offset of the failed record. There is only one committed offset per partition.

You can either throw an exception (and the `DefaultErrorHandler` will perform the necessary seeks so that the current record will be redelivered, until retries are exhausted).

Or, you can call `nack()` on the acknowledgment, which will do the same (but has no concept of retry exhaustion).

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#committing-offsets

Comment: did I understand correctly - that until I do the commit offset, I can’t get the next message for the current consumer (in the current partition and except Failure-Stratgy = dead-letter-queue)? And I can only use nack() or DefaultErrorHandler to re-process this fawl message until I do a commune?

Comment: That is correct; if you process the next record, and it is from the same partition, and you commit its offset, you will implicitly commit the previous record's offset (there is only one offset per partition). We do provide a mechanism to write that record to a retry topic, which allows you to continue processing the following records, and retry this one later; see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic

Comment: I read this article, but I can’t understand where topics are created to store unprocessed messages - is this some kind of local application cache?

Comment: No, Spring creates the additional retry topics, based on the primary topic name and other configuration. When a listener fails, the record is sent to the next retry topic.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but where are these topics created for repetitions? Does in the bootstrap-servers or every application listen to the topics create topics for repetitions in themselves?
If on bobootstrap-servers, for example, having connected through Kafka-Tools, these new topics will be visible?

Comment: Yes, they are created on the same cluster as the primary topic. Only applications properly configured will listen on the retry topics. Yes, they are just normal topics, visible o all.